# How do I lookup Blockchain sizes for crypto-currencies like Litecoin and Dogecoin?

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, dogecoin

I am new to mining cryptocurrencies. I am planning to set up a wallet for both Litecoin and Dogecoin. I am just curious on asking what are the current total blockchain sizes of both coins? This is to prepare me to download them ahead of time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: Could be improved to read "How can I know in advance the total blockchain size of a crypto-currency, at any single point in time, without having to install the client and wait for the blockchain to download?" In which case it'd be much more useful and less time- and coin- dependent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bitinfocharts.com](http://bitinfocharts.com/) lists stats for the main cryptos including the block chain size. You will find "Blockchain size" near the bottom.

Comment: It is hard to locate that webpage in the internet searches. I found it faster from stack results :V

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://block-explorer.com/ and http://dogechain.info/ to see the latest number of each currency. In each blockexplorer the latest block is in the first row so you can see the total amount of blocks from the id of this block.

As of now(25th Dec. 2013) Litecoin is roughly 500000 blocks and Dogecoin 30000 blocks.

From an estimation of my dogecoin wallet the average block is about 30 MB (based on 2,4 GB data and 77000 blocks) but it highly depends on the current amount of transactions.

Comment: He asked for the size of the blockchain. Not the number of coins in circulation.

Comment: What do you want? On that date there were 30000 doge BLOCKS and 500000 litecoin BLOCKS. The amount of coins at that time was much higher considerring that one block of doge is 1000000 doge. I don't see a problem and no real reason to downvote my answer. The only thing he could have wanted would be the size in bytes but this is not what you are complaining about.

Comment: Please edit your answer, it's not clear: it seems you're answering the number of "coins" for each crypto-currency rather than "blocks". If you could providea screenshot or slightly more info in the text, it'd be way better (y). And much, much better, should you add a formula to translate the # of blocks to the bytes size on harddisk, even if just approximately

Comment: I understand your comment and tried to improve my post but I do not think it is that hard to look at a table that you have to include a screenshot as a help.

Answer (score 1):

https://bchain.info/LTC/ has blockchain size in lower right hand corner.